# Separating strings with lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to find a way to separate strings in a project of my called 'Chemistry Calculator'. This project takes strings from an *input()* and compare it in a list:

```
    substance1 = input('Substance 1: ')
    substance2 = input('Substance 2: ')
    elements = ['f','o','cl','br','i','s','c']

    def affinity_table(element1:str,element2:str,table:list) -> str:
        s = element1.lower()
        r = element2.lower()
        if s in table and r in table:

            if table.index(s) < table.index(r):
                print(s," will chage with ", r)

            else:
                print(s," won't change with ", r)

        else:
            print("Those substances are't in the list")
```

This code above works well.

So I wanted to have it working with hole substances and not just the element.  To do this I need to separate the substance in to parts:

- the cations parts
- the anions parts.

Then I need to compare them with the list. I noticed that the *contains()* function showed exactly what I wanted, but only with one comparison.

My question came from: 
Is there a way of using the *contains()* function with more than one string and then separate the string in to where the similarity is found.

Something similar to this:

```
a = 'NaCO3' #First input.
b = 'KCO3'  #Second input.
list = ['Na','K']   #The list.

# Way of separating the values with the list.
     # ^ my objective.
a1 = 'Na' #Separation with a.
a2 = 'CO3' #The rest of a.
b1 = 'K' #The rest of b.
b2 = 'CO3' #The rest of b.
     # ^ expected outputs from the separation.
if table.index(a1) < table.index(a2):
      print(a1,' will change with ', b1, 'and become', a1 + b2)

else:
      print(a1," won't change with ", b1, 'and will stay normal')
            # ^ the list index comparison from the 1st code.
```

#After the solution, here are the results:
 [image: The Results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

Just to be clear: for the constrained scope of what you are doing this solution might be applicable. If you want to parse any chemical compound (and those can look quite complicated) you need a full fledged parser, not the toy regex solution I came up with.

---

Here's an idea:

Dynamically build a regex with elements from your list as alternating matching groups. (`re.split` keeps groups when splitting.)

```
>>> import re
>>> lst = ['Na', 'K']
>>> regex = '|'.join('({})'.format(a) for a in lst)
>>> regex
>>> '(Na)|(K)'
```

Apply the regex...

```
>>> re.split(regex, 'NaCO3')
>>> ['', 'Na', None, 'CO3']
>>> re.split(regex, 'KCO3')
>>> ['', None, 'K', 'CO3']
```

... and filter out falsy values (`None`, `''`)

```
>>> list(filter(None, re.split(regex, 'NaCO3')))
>>> ['Na', 'CO3']
>>> list(filter(None, re.split(regex, 'KCO3')))
>>> ['K', 'CO3']
```

You can assign to those values with extended iterable unpacking:

```
>>> b1, b2, *unexpected_rest = filter(None, re.split(regex, 'KCO3'))
>>> b1
>>> 'K'
>>> b2
>>> 'CO3'
```

If you want to bias the split in favor of longer matches, sort `lst` in descending order first.

Not good:

```
>>> lst = ['N', 'Na', 'CO3']
>>> regex = '|'.join('({})'.format(a) for a in lst)
>>> list(filter(None, re.split(regex, 'NaCO3')))
>>> ['N', 'a', 'CO3']
```

Better:

```
>>> lst = ['N', 'Na', 'CO3']
>>> lst = sorted(lst, key=len, reverse=True)
>>> regex = '|'.join('({})'.format(a) for a in lst)
>>> list(filter(None, re.split(regex, 'NaCO3')))
>>> ['Na', 'CO3']
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: One potential problem is that most single letter element symbols can be mistakenly matched when there's a different element with a symbol that starts with the same letter. For example Nitrogen (N) / Sodium (Na) or Oxygen (O) and Osmium (Os). Maybe use a negative lookahead `(Na|O|N)(?![a-z])` works?

Comment: Man this seams very good, but just one question, what exactly the _re_  function does? And the above guy is right, there is a way to differentiate them? (Basically that was the reason I choose to do a list comparison where all the variables follows the 'Chemistry Grammar').

Comment: `re` is the python standard library regular expressions module.  https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html

Comment: So basically, the function you wrote there just accept separation when the part is the same, but, as said, in a situation where you are comparing `'N'` and the `str` is `"NaOH"` the result would be `"N", "aOH"`.

Comment: Yes, which is why you might want to use a "negative lookahead", which is supported by `re`. See my comment above. In this case `(N|O)(?![a-z])` only matches N or O when there's not a lower case letter `[a-z]` just after. `(?!...)` is this regular expression dialect's syntax for a negative lookahead assertion.

Comment: Here's a useful website for testing and understanding regular expressions: https://regex101.com/r/vXDzKZ/1

Comment: @HåkenLid we are able to bias in favor of longer matches by sorting `lst`.

Comment: Now that is very good! All my tryouts were successful, many thanks to you  Haken Lid ;)

Comment: I now that the bigger the compound the crazier the code must be, but for now I'm just starting to see what I can accomplish with stuff as simple as NaOH or KOH  and your code was perfect to this b'cause I can even do this to the rest of the compound and  make it (even in its simplicity) more "chemistry correct".

Comment: @Locochoco cool, glad I could help. It's nice to see fellow chemists on stackoverflow. :)